# BlueJ not running keyadapter at all

Tags: java, swing, bluej

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
Timer time;
Image Border;
Image Dude;
Image Road;
Image GZombie;
Image RZombie;
Image BZombie;
MovingPiece player;

public Board()
{
//set this window to be the one receiving keystrokes
addKeyListener(new AL());
setFocusable(true);
ImageIcon dude = new ImageIcon("Dude.png");            //player
Dude=dude.getImage();       
                   //      Cx and Cy are changed in move methods, they are change in (x/y)   
                   //  X   Y  W  H  CxCy Speed Image
player=new MovingPiece(200,300,50,50,0,0,2,Dude);
time=new Timer(5,this);
time.start();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){   
player.setX(player.getX() + player.getCx()); //adds my x to my change in x
player.setY(player.getY() + player.getCy()); //im sure u can figure this one out...
//redraw the screen
repaint();
}

public void paint(Graphics g){        
super.paint(g);
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
g2d.drawImage(player.getImage(),player.getX(),player.getY(),null);  //draw player
}

//the key listener, it is a private class inside of the Board class

private class AL extends KeyAdapter{

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){           
int key = e.getKeyCode();
System.out.println(key);        //*THIS IS WHAT WONT RUN*
if(key==KeyEvent.VK_W){player.moveUp();}        //this changes my cy to be -speed which is -2
if(key==KeyEvent.VK_A){player.moveDown();}      //this changes my cy to be speed which is 2
if(key==KeyEvent.VK_S){player.moveLeft();}      //I made this simple.. this is cx
if(key==KeyEvent.VK_D){player.moveRight();}     //take a guess. 
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
int key = e.getKeyCode();
if(key==KeyEvent.VK_W){player.setCy(0);}        //stops my changes in y so I don't move up/down
if(key==KeyEvent.VK_A){player.setCx(0);}        //quite repetitive. 
if(key==KeyEvent.VK_S){player.setCy(0);}
if(key==KeyEvent.VK_D){player.setCx(0);}
    }
 }   
}
```

Basically my keyadapter wont run. The print of what key is, is not important.
But it is an indicator to see if the method is running, or if the problem was with my move methods.
well since it isn't printing, then the method itself is not running. and thus it is not my move methods. it must be this adapter. I just want to know why it isn't working. I have set focusable which is all the other forums say to do. so. please help. thanks in advance

Comment: Add `requestFocusInWindow` after `setFocusable`

Comment: Use [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) and save yourself a mess of problems